# Sparkpost API: Bulk mailing with different template per recipient

Tags: sparkpost

I am trying to use bulk mailing/mass mailing to a large number of recipients.

However, the emails must go out in different languages.

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35628731/1132363) the accepted answer [states the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631217/1132363):

> For the multi-lingual use case, you might consider creating a template per language as many of our other customers do.

So, how do I specify a different template (each template is in a different language) per recipient when sending out emails in bulk?

Comment: Have you considered passing the text that needs to be in different languages as per-recipient substitution variables, and updating your template to pull those in? You might also find the upcoming [snippets feature](https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/snippets-for-more-dynamic-stored-templates/) useful, once that's generally available, although that doesn't help right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify different template per recipient. But I guess you have a number of recipients per language. You can send separate request for each language group and specify corresponding template.

Also if your template isn't big, you can put some of the language strings in recipient level substitutions. That may not ideal for all cases though.

Comment: I've considered this, but it kind of defeats the purpose of even using templates. If I have to manually group emails then I might as well have a local template with translatable strings. I would only need to have one as opposed to making multiple in SparkPost.